# How can I make ffmpeg open my raw video file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, transcoding

I'm trying to convert a raw video-only file to some other formats but all I'm getting ffmpeg to produce is a black video.
There are no error messages displayed and this is what ffprobe shows when analyzing the file:

> ffprobe version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>   built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
>   configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.2 --enable-shared
>   --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda   libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100   libavcodec     57. 64.101 /
>   57. 64.101   libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100   libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100   libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100   libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0   libswscale      4.  2.100 / 
>   4.  2.100   libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100   libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100 Input #0, avi, from '1.avi':   Metadata:
>       encoder         : Lavf54.20.4   Duration: 00:00:57.43, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 83196 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, pal8, 720x480, 83238 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc

Other input files can be transcoded to a playable outfile file with the same ffmpeg convert command:

> ffmpeg -i 1.avi -vcodec h264 output.avi

I know the input video is not corrupted because VLC plays it successfully and can even convert it to other formats, but I want to preserve the original one when trying different configurations using ffmpeg.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question, and is thus off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It will probably be a better fit on our sister site [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Does ffplay play the file?

Comment: You might need to tell `ffmpeg` the pixel format: `ffmpeg -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -i 1.avi -vcodec h264 output.avi`, but it's hard to answer without having access to the input file. Also note: Joe C is right, move your question to Super User site.

Comment: Try defining the codec before specifying the input file: ffmpeg -f h264 -i 1.avi -vcodec copy -acodec aac output.avi and it's probably better to use mp4 container.

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` cannot "guess" the video details from the raw video stream. Therefore, the details should be explicitly specified to `ffmpeg` when input file is a raw video.

As minimum, the video resolution and frame format should be provided.
In this particular case the command would be:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt pal8 -video_size 720x480 -i 1.avi -vcodec h264 output.avi
```